# JSF/Primefaces components in VIEWMODE, EDITMODE, CREATEMODE

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have around 10 tables in my database. Building CRUD’s for these are easy with ie. reverse engineering in Netbeans, and with Netbeans 8 the pages look great thanks to primefaces.

So now I have 4 pages per entity; list, create, edit and view. Create and edit are similar except they bind to a new respective an existing entity. View is similar to edit, except it is readonly. The available buttons change too, of course, and there are probably other minor differences.

What I would like is to keep it down to 2 components per entity; 1 for the list and 1 for an instance. The latter should come in 3 flavours; editmode, createmode and viewmode. These components should be includeable in other pages, preferably both as dialogs and “raw” imports.

Anyone have an idea whether this is possible? Do I need to create my own set of renders, which can ie. render an inputText-component and a selectOneMenu as an outputText? As an example my first try with an inputText was just to write disabled=”true”, which renders the inputtext as non-editable. It becomes too greyish, but I guess that would be fixable by overriding the style. But preferrably it should render as a real outputText would when in viewmode. Maybe some clever use of css could do the job instead of renders.

Maybe the easiest way would be to store the viewmode of the composite component in the componenttree.  Is this possible? I guess any component would have to look up in the tree in the render phase, to see how it should render.

For the buttons I could maybe do with just the rendered attribute.

Is it possible to go this route, or has anyone already made a framework for this? Or is it stretching JSF too far?